# Damage Over Time Area code not working, while using very similar code to Ground Check that is working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to C# and Unity and am working on a simple platformer for a school project. I'm currently trying to get a piece of group that does damage over time to the player. To detect whether the player is on this piece of ground, I thought I could use the same code as I did for my ground check, but with altered variable names etc. However the ground check code works, and the detection for the damage over time doesn't and I have no idea why.

```cs
void CheckIfGrounded()
{
    Collider2D collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(isGroundedChecker.position, checkGroundRadius, groundLayer);
    if (collider != null)
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            lastTimeGrounded = Time.time;
        }
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}

void CheckIfDOT()
{
    Collider2D collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(isDOT.position, checkDOT_AreaRadius, DOT_AreaLayer);
    if (collider != null)
    {
        damageOverTime = true;
    }
    else
    {
        damageOverTime = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are these called and where/how is `damageOverTime` used?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you need to know how `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` works.

As in unity documentation, it says :

> Checks if a Collider falls within a circular area.
> The circle is defined by its centre coordinate in world space and by its radius.

It means that from one point, which is position, they will draw a circle have radius like the radius you use and if there is any collider is in that range, it will result in the collider2d, like your example.

You need to check :

- Where is that point : In the player or in the obstacles ?
- Is the circle big enough for collider to fall within ? ( depends on radius )

Try to use `Debug.Log()` to show if the function is executed normally